# Search EVERYTHING by default

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results

My users noticed fairly quickly once we moved to SharePoint Online that now when you search while you are within a subsite, it only searches the local site.

For my company, it makes more sense that it searches everything by default. Is there a way within the tenant level settings to search EVERYTHING by default rather than just the local site?

Answer (score 1):

You could go to the search page in the sub site when searching.

Then edit the search result page, edit search result web part, click change query, select “Local SharePoint Results(System)” result source and save the changes.

After all, it will search within all site collections in the SharePoint online.

[image]

Comment: Well that is one solution. But I have nearly 100 subsites - any way to do this in mass or change at the tenant level? It is one site that seems to have the most trouble with this, so it would help, but if I could just do it for everything in one go. It wasn't this way on-prem and I have no clue why it changed when it went to online.

Comment: I am afraid you will change it in sub site one by one.